# How do I store an automator action in version control (git)?

Tags: automator, git

I just created an Automator 'application' action and it works fine but I want to have version control of it.

Automator creates a bundle that seems to be a bunch of XML and resources which is a pretty crappy way to manage software source code.

Is there a way to do this?  Or should I be creating a 'regular' AppleScript instead of an Automator action?

Comment: You can add the entire "bundle" into git. The contained files will be tracked individually.

Comment: Thank you but, especially with embedded shell scripts, the bundle format obstructs the ability to review code changes.  The script is wrapped fairly deep in XML